# Can't change background of actionbar in Android Studio

Tags: android-actionbar

I want to change the background of actionbar but it doesn't work. The code is rather simple:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTheme"
parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/green1</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/green1</item>
</style>

<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</activity>
```

green1 is a picture in drawable. I run the program, the actionbar shows as the default theme instead of the picture I want. What is the problem? Really confused.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `AppTheme` Use `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">`, your `ActionBarTheme` should use:

```
<style name="ActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
       ... ...
</style>
```

replace:

```
<style name="ActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
       ... ...
</style>
```

othewise if your `AppTheme` use `DarkActionBar` then your `ActionBarTheme` use `Solid.Inverse` is ok

Comment: I change ActionBarTheme as you said but it still doesn't work

Comment: which API level your device using